# Probably a dumb question on integration(Geometry of a simple double integral of $x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to integrate $\int \int_D x \;\mathrm{dA}$

With D being the area enclosed by a rectangle $(0,0),(3,0),(3,1),(0,1)$

Now I would think the integral should be setup as:
$\int_0^1 \int_0^3 x dx dy$, but this equals $4.5$ and I can't geometrically mentally picture what this integral looks like, it is 2D is it not? I think I am just tired, but I can't make sense of it. Any ideas?

It has to be 3D I guess, because my region has max area of $3$

Comment: See [Double Integral][1]


  [1]: http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/255doub/255doub.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your region is 3D (3 x 1 x 1).

You are integrating f(x,y)=x.

Choosing x as your inner integral evaluates as (x^2)/2 from 0 to 3 or 9/2.

Evaluating the outer integral gives you 9/2y from 0 to 1, which is also 9/2 or 4.5.

Hope this helps,

Regards,

Laine

Comment: That does help. That makes perfect sense, thank you.